# How can I get a python program to restart and close an existing tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to figure out how to restart a python program with Tkinter. Basically, when the user clicks on the restart button, the program should close all existing Tkinter tabs and "restart" the program. How can I do this?

This is what I am currently doing

```
        def Restart(root,root2,root3):

            fh = open(".exeinfo/AccountData/Filepath.baseconfig",'r')
            path = fh.read()
            call(["Restart.bat"])
            root2.destroy()
            try:
                root.destroy()
            except:
                pass
            try:
                root3.destroy()
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would say that you should put the entirety of the code within a loop, but tkinter breaks that, so what I will suggest is a solution that is very unclean; two more simple scripts to run alongside this one.

The first is a simple multiprocess one, something along the lines of using multiprocess to run your current script/application through alongside another.

Then add this to the end of your function you've made here to restart the program:

```
f = open("restart.txt", "w+")
f.write("true")
f.close()
exit() #or however you choose to end your program after destroying the roots
```

And this to the start of your script/application (before anything else is done, except importing stuff):

```
r = open("restart.txt", "w+")
r.write("false")
r.close()
```

Finally, in the third script just add a simple loop:

```
x = 5
while x = 5:
f = open("restart.txt", "r+")
restart = f.read()
if restart == "true":
#run your application/script
else:
f.close()
```

The goal of this would be to run your application, and this simple loop simultaneously. When you want to restart your program, you would update the text file to "true" and close the program, and then the simple loop would run your program again, which would change the value to false and prevent infinite windows of your program being opened. I doubt this is the best solution, nor exactly what you wanted, but it should "restart" your program.